# PHP encoding JPEG from ftp location without local file

Tags: php, image, jpeg, in-memory

Task is to read a JPEG from a ftp location and encode it to base64 without any local saving in between.

This is my coding so far:

```php
$memstream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $memstream, $imgLocation, FTP_BINARY)) {
    rewind($memstream);
    ob_start();
        imagejpeg($memstream);
        $contents = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean();
    $vCard->add('PHOTO', base64_encode($contents), ['TYPE' => 'JPEG', 'ENCODING' => 'b']);
    fclose($memstream);
}
```

But I receive at the line `imagejpeg($memstream);` the error: supplied resource is not a valid Image resource...

I check the resource with saving the downloaded image local:

```php
$imgFile = fopen('test.jpg', 'r+');
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $imgFile, $imgLocation, FTP_BINARY)) {
    fclose($imgFile);
}
```

and it´s fine.

So I´m a little bit puzzled, why the same resource shouldn´t be valid if I store it in memory?

Comment: Some observations: 1) you're not checking whether `imagejpeg` succeeds or fails. 2) `ob_get_contents()` gets the content of the current output buffer. This has no relationship to `$memstream` as far as I can see.

Comment: What is `imagejpeg` doing in there in the first place? That is part of the GDLib, which you use for actual image _manipulation_. According to your question, you don’t want to do any image manipulation here, you just want to grab the content of the image from the FTP, and output that base64 encoded … so this should not use any graphic library functions at all, this is a simple _file_ operation; that the file happens to be an image - absolutely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The second comment led me to the right question. Then Google was kind enough to point me to `stream_get_contents`:

```php
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $memStream, $imgLocation, FTP_BINARY)) {
    rewind($memStream);
    $contents = stream_get_contents($memStream);
    $vCard->add('PHOTO', base64_encode($contents), ['TYPE' => 'JPEG', 'ENCODING' => 'b']);
    fclose($memStream);
}
```